# Stratified Sampling of a DataFrame

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe

Given a dataframe with columns "a", "b", and "value", I'd like to sample N rows from each pair of ("a", "b").  In python pandas, this is easy to do with the following syntax:

```py
import pandas as pd
df.groupby(["a", "b"]).sample(n=10)
```

In Julia, I found a way to achieve something similar using:

```
using DataFrames, StatsBase

combine(groupby(df, [:a, :b]),
names(df) .=> sample .=> names(df)
)
```

However, I don't know how to extend this to n>1.  I tried

```
combine(groupby(df, [:a, :b]),
names(df) .=> x -> sample(x, n) .=> names(df)
)
```

but this returned the error (for `n=3`):

> DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size; got a dimension with lengths 3 and 7")

One method (with slightly different syntax) that I found was:

```
combine(groupby(df, [:a, :b]), x -> x[sample(1:nrow(x), n), :])
```

but I'm interested in knowing if there are better alternatives

Comment: The last example you gave is a normal way to do it. Note that in this case it is enough to use `rand` instead of `sample`. `sample` would be needed if you wanted sampling without replacement.

Comment: Point well taken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe as an additional comment. If you have an id column in your data frame (holding a row number) then:

```
df[combine(groupby(df, [:a, :b]), :id => (x -> rand(x, n)) => :id).id, :]
```

will be a bit faster (but not by much).

Here is an example:

```
using DataFrames
n = 10
df = DataFrame(a=rand(1:1000, 10^8), b=rand(1:1000, 10^8), id=1:10^8)
combine(groupby(df, [:a, :b]), x -> x[rand(1:nrow(x), n), :]); # around 16.5 seconds on my laptop
df[combine(groupby(df, [:a, :b]), :id => (x -> rand(x, n)) => :id).id, :]; # around 14 seconds on my laptop
```